# Meteor Collection relationship with users

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, collections, meteor

I have some collections related, one of them is `Decisions` which has this field

`submittedBy: {
        type: Schema.user,
        autoValue: function() {
            if (this.isInsert) {
                return this.userId;
            } else {
                this.unset();
            }
        }
    }`

So when a logged user posts a `Decision`, this field contains his userId, but when I retrieve data into HTML using `{{#each}}`, field `{{submittedBy}}` has only it's userId... I want to retrieve user's object in or ther to manipulate it, for example render username for text and userId for a `<a href="/users/{{ submittedBy.userId }}">{{ submittedBy.username }}</a>` tag.

Extended `Users` has this field

`decisions: {
        type: [Schema.Decision],
        optional: true
    }`

Which I want to be filled with each `Decision` user has posted...

I am using `autoforms` and `collection2` here are full schemas, if you want to have a look

```
Decisions = new Meteor.Collection("decisions");

var Schema = {};

Schema.Decision = new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Título",
        max: 149
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        label: "Descripción",
        max: 149,
        optional: true
    },
    blue: {
        type: String,
        label: "Opción Azul",
        max: 149
    },
    blueTotal: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Votos Azules",
        min: 0,
        defaultValue: 0,
        optional: true
    },
    red: {
        type: String,
        label: "Opción Roja",
        max: 149
    },
    redTotal: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Votos Rojos",
        min: 0,
        defaultValue: 0,
        optional: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Fecha envío",
        optional: true,
        autoValue: function () {
            if (this.isInsert) {
                return new Date;
            } else {
                this.unset();
            }
        },
        denyUpdate: true
    },
    submittedBy: {
        type: Schema.user,
        autoValue: function() {
            if (this.isInsert) {
                return this.userId;
            } else {
                this.unset();
            }
        }
    },
    tags: {
        type: [String],
        label: "Tags",
        minCount: 1
    }
});
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/
    },
    emails: {
        type: [Object]
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
    decisions: {
        type: [Schema.Decision],
        optional: true
    }
});
Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,25}$/,
        optional: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,25}$/,
        optional: true
    },
    birthday: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
    },
    gender: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female'],
        optional: true
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Url,
        optional: true
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    country: {
        type: Schema.UserCountry,
        optional: true
    }
});
Schema.UserCountry = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    code: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[A-Z]{2}$/
    }
});

Decisions.allow({
    insert: function() {
        return true;
    },
    update: function() {
        return false;
    },
    remove: function() {
        return false;
    },
    fetch: []
});
Decisions.attachSchema(Schema.Decision);
Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

Comment: It's generally a good practice not to duplicate the data you've got in DB. So if you already have `decisions` as a collection, you shouldn't store them as an array in user model. Also if `decision` has an user id pointing to `users` collection, then `user` model shouldn't have an array of `decisions` ids pointing the other way. Is there a good reason you want to break this rule?

Comment: Is just I come from SQL Models and starting with No-SQL, now I barely understand that I can get user's Decisions just getting userId from Decision and then searching that user data with submittedBy, am I right? I just find it "slower" than a oneToMany relationship...

Comment: For most use cases it's not significantly slower, assuming you have proper indexes in the db. Reducing redundancy is far more important as it prevents problems with data integrity as the application grows – see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).